# IoHub for eye tracking

Tags: python-2.7, psychopy, eye-tracking

1. Can ioHub be used with Eye Tribe glasses?
2. Using ioHub, is it possible to detect sacaddic, blinks, and fixations?

Answer (score 1):

I have not used EyeTribe (and don't use ioHub), but we do use Psychopy for eye tracking. And for us we just connect to the eye tracker using tcp/ip communication from Python itself. And the EyeTribe website under the API section says:

> If you favor any other programming language the open API relies on the standard TCP/IP protocol. If it can open a socket and parse strings then you’re covered.

And you can certainly do that in Python, so if you want to use these glasses I am sure you can, but it will likely require some work on your part. I had an undergrad who got a Mirametrix tracker talking to Python/Psychopy and he left some of his experience detailed here: https://brittlab.uwaterloo.ca/research-tips/

But make sure that the technical specifications (60 Hz and a 20 ms latency) will be sufficient for your needs. I find with eye trackers what you pay for is what you get. There is another nice open source option with a higher speed camera and very supportive developmen team at http://pupil-labs.com/pupil/

Good luck, Please add a comment later on your experience if you get these to work, because alot of us, like you, are looking for cheaper tracking options.